# Custom comment syntax for WebStorm/PHPStorm for Javascript?

Tags: phpstorm, webstorm

I'm having a hard time to figure out how the change the comment style in Jetbrains. When typing /** and enter, it fills in JSDoc compatible comments. Are there any quick solutions to 
change this template ? 
thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You should try: 
Settings (Section IDE Settings) -> File and Code Templates -> PHP Function Doc Commment.

You can change that template to your liking.
There is a list with all available placeholders, too.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to make doc comments generation use the different comment style. If you miss this feature, please create a request in [youtrack](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WEB)